# Can't pass two parameters to action ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, routes

I want to pass id and quantity to action, but I get this error: parameter dictionary contains a null entry for parameter `id`.

I've tried to do map routing, but I can't find how to do it properly.

My Action:

```csharp
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int id, int quantity) 
{
     var user = unitOfWork.Users.FindByEmail(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
     unitOfWork.Carts.AddProductToCartByEmail(user.Email, id, quantity);
     unitOfWork.Complete();
     return View();
}
```

From this page I'm trying to pass the parameters:

```razor
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;

@model IPagedList<MVC_Task.Models.AllProductsModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Products</h2>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Price)
        </th>
        @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            <th>
                Quantity
            </th>
        }
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Product", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
                </td>
                @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <td class="form-inline">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Quantity, new { @type = "number", @class = "form-control" })

                        <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default"
                               onclick="window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", new { item.Id, item.Quantity})';" /> //on this line I send the parameters
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>

<center>@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))</center>
```

Answer (score 1):

In post actions there is only one parameter can be taken from body, all other parameters you may pass them as route parametes or query string parameters, so your signature

```
public ActionResult Index(int id, int quantity)
```

may become:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id, [FromBody] int quantity)
```

you can call the action using the url /index?id=...

and try to call the action using ajax post or submit the form not a hyperlink

for more information see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody

Comment: Nice suggestion about ajax and the single parameter from the body.

Comment: I'm not able to use this attribute. (
Visual Studio doesn't propose me any libraries for it.

Comment: @Morin also you may use a wrapper object (DTO or Data Transfer Object / View Model...) to group all parameters all together, then you don't need the [FromBody] attribute in case you can't find it. In case you need to use FromBody attribute you may add using System.Web.Http; namespace

Comment: I tried to use DTO, but the object is null on POST.

Answer (score 0):

You're not really posting correctly, using the client side `window.location.href` - it will result in a HttpGet.

You should add a hidden input for the item id, here's the relevant snippet:

```razor
<td class="form-inline">

   <!-- add the hidden input -->
   @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.Id)

   <!-- keep this as is -->
   @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Quantity, new { @type = "number", @class = "form-control" })

   <!-- remove the onclick redirect, 
        this will post to the action defined in BeginForm -->
   <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-default"/>
</td>
```

---

Next, a model is often passed as a complex type. It has many benefits over simple types, because you can extend it with, e.g.; validation logic.

So, lets define a model:

```
public class PostModel
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public int Quantity {get;set;}
}
```

Now adjust your `Index` to accept the model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(PostModel model) 
{
   //your logic
}
```

By default the binders will bind to the appropriate properties in the model. If your TextBox's `name` is `Id`, or `Quantity`, it will be able to do so. You can validate that in the rendered html.

Comment: I've tried that, didn't help. I have the same problem.

Comment: Ah, yes, its easier to use a complex type, let me adjust

Comment: I used `AllProductsModels` that I have, but it seems like it doesn't bind correctly.
I've no values on `ActionResult`.

Comment: @Morin: can you post the outputted html, for the 2 textbox and hidden input?

Comment: Btw, we can always default to simple html elements, that will definitely work

Comment: How do I find the outputted html?
I'm really new in that.

Comment: If you look at the page from your browser: press F12 to open the devtools web debugging. You will see ton of actions, stats etc. One of them shows the actual HTML without razor. Including your textbox and hidden input. You can also capture the post request and inspect the content its actually posting

Comment: This is what I get.

Quantity:
`<input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Quantity must be a number." data-val-required="The Quantity field is required." id="item_Quantity" name="item.Quantity" type="number" value="0">`

Comment: Id:
`<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="item_Id" name="item.Id" type="hidden" value="1">`